# Error in installing csidrvier to a kubernetes namesapce - This command needs 1 argument: chart name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-keyvault, mount

I am a Kubernetes novice. I am trying to install a csi driver to a Kubernetes Namespace in a kubernetes cluster. I am using helm 2.16 version to do the install using below command :

`.\helm install csi-secrets-store secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver -n csi`

`Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name`

Also tried running :

`.\helm install csi-secrets-store secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver --namespace csi` and get below Error :

`Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name`

Can some one help me with the correct command?

`.\helm version`

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.12", GitCommit:"47f0b88409e71fd9ca272abc7cd762a56a1c613e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.1", GitCommit:"bbdfe5e7803a12bbdf97e94cd847859890cf4050", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Helm v2 is quite old now.  It looks like the `helm install` syntax you have is the Helm v3 version (the release name became a mandatory positional argument).  Can you upgrade Helm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://v2-14-0.helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-install):

> This command installs a chart archive.
>
> The install argument must be a chart reference, a path to a packaged
> chart, a path to an unpacked chart directory or a URL.
>
> To override values in a chart, use either the `–values` flag and pass
> in a file or use the `–set` flag and pass configuration from the
> command line. To force string values in `–set`, use `–set-string`
> instead. In case a value is large and therefore you want not to use
> neither `–values` nor `–set`, use `–set-file` to read the single large
> value from file.
>
> CHART REFERENCES
>
> A chart reference is a convenient way of reference a chart in a chart
> repository.
>
> When you use a chart reference with a repo prefix (‘stable/mariadb’),
> Helm will look in the local configuration for a chart repository named
> ‘stable’, and will then look for a chart in that repository whose name
> is ‘mariadb’. It will install the latest version of that chart unless
> you also supply a version number with the ‘–version’ flag.
>
> To see the list of chart repositories, use ‘helm repo list’. To search
> for charts in a repository, use ‘helm search’.
>
> ```
> helm install [CHART] [flags]
> ```

Note the:

```
-n, --name string          release name. If unspecified, it will autogenerate one for you
```

and:

```
--namespace string         namespace to install the release into. Defaults to the current kube config namespace.
```

The error you see means that you did not reference the chart name properly. It looks like there are too many arguments for `--name` (`csi-secrets-store` and `csi`). For example it should look more like this:

```
helm install --name <release name> --namespace <namespace>
```

which would be transleted into your use case as:

```
helm install --name csi-secrets-store secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver --namespace csi
```

*Note that I am not sure of the values you want to use so you have to check them yourself and adjust if needed. Here I assume that `csi` is the namespace, `csi-secrets-store` is the release name and `secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver` is the repo/chart name.

Also make sure that the chart you want to install does not require Helm v3.0+. If so, than you will have to upgrade it before installing.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor - your sugesstion worked , but I end up with another issue:.\helm install --name csi-secrets-store secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver --namespace csi
Error: render error in "secrets-store-csi-driver/templates/csidriver.yaml": template: secrets-store-csi-driver/templates/_helpers.tpl:40:45: executing "csidriver.apiVersion" at <.Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version>: can't evaluate field Version in type *version.Info

Comment: Hmm, that would be a different story. In order to not mix up different topics I recommend asking another question and explaining this particular error. Remember to show the `csidriver.yaml` as well so the community could see where the problem is and help you with it.